# Creating two 1D lists from python based on function returning two entries

Tags: python

I have a function `f(x,y)` which returns two values `a,b`.

I want to construct a 2D List from returned values of `a,b` from `f` being called on `x` in a List of values and `y` in an equally long list of values.

Is there an easy way to do this?

I tried this and it did not work.

```
aList, bList = [f(x[i],y[i],1) for i in range(T)]
```

Comment: Probably it doesn't exist.

Comment: Check spelling of the filename

Comment: You should also add the relevant data. Using strings as examples are not relevant since your text file contains numbers.

Comment: Will each line contain the same number of words?

Comment: Are you using `numpy`?  This is pretty easy in `numpy`.  Otherwise, you will get a list of 2-tuples that you'll need to split by hand.   Not hard.

Comment: @TimRoberts When is it recommended to use numpy? when is it recommended to work with lists?

Comment: Volume, mostly.  If this is the only manipulation you do of these arrays, then `numpy` is overkill.  If you're doing other arithmetic, then `numpy` is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the the `*-operator` to perform [argument unpacking of the list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=unpacking#unpacking-argument-lists) while calling [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to compose the two desired lists.

```py
input_data = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)]

def f(x, y):
    return x+1, y-1

results = [f(i[0], i[1]) for i in input_data]

print (f"results: {results}")

a_list, b_list = zip(*results)

print(f"a_list: {a_list}\nb_list: {b_list}")

# This is equivalent to what the *-operator does above, in that
# it is unpacking the list of tuples into a series of arguments
# to zip().
a_list2, b_list2 = zip(results[0], results[1], results[2])

print(f"a_list2: {a_list2}\nb_list2: {b_list2}")
```

Output:

```sh
$ python3 solution.py
results: [(1, -1), (2, 0), (3, 1)]
a_list: (1, 2, 3)
b_list: (-1, 0, 1)
a_list2: (1, 2, 3)
b_list2: (-1, 0, 1)
```

Using the `*-operator` for unpacking is convenient because it can seamlessly scale with the number of arguments to `zip()`.

```py
import random

def f(num_results):
    return tuple(random.randint(1,10) for n in range(num_results))

for num_results in range(4,7):
    print(f"\nHandling {num_results} values per tuple...")

    results = [f(num_results) for _ in range(3)]
    print(f"results: {results}")
    # Note the use unpacking in the assignment as well to 
    # capture a variable number of lists.
    *x_lists, = zip(*results)
    for *x_list, in x_lists:
        print(x_list)
```

Output:

```sh
$ python3 solution2.py

Handling 4 values per tuple...
results: [(4, 5, 7, 1), (8, 9, 9, 3), (6, 3, 9, 4)]
[4, 8, 6]
[5, 9, 3]
[7, 9, 9]
[1, 3, 4]

Handling 5 values per tuple...
results: [(6, 3, 3, 9, 9), (10, 1, 1, 5, 4), (3, 10, 8, 3, 2)]
[6, 10, 3]
[3, 1, 10]
[3, 1, 8]
[9, 5, 3]
[9, 4, 2]

Handling 6 values per tuple...
results: [(5, 5, 10, 8, 1, 6), (7, 5, 8, 7, 9, 1), (5, 5, 1, 1, 10, 5)]
[5, 7, 5]
[5, 5, 5]
[10, 8, 1]
[8, 7, 1]
[1, 9, 10]
[6, 1, 5]
```

Comment: Can you explain more on the *operator in your answer?

Comment: Added a better documentation link and provided an example of manually performing the argument unpacking for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You always need to think about what you HAVE vs what you WANT.  The list comprehension returns a single list containing 2-tuples.  You need to split that list.

```
result = [f(x[i],y[i],1) for i in range(T)]
aList = [k[0] for k in result]
bList = [k[1] for k in result]
```